# URL extraction from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I found a regular expression that is suppose to capture URLs but it doesn't capture some URLs.

```
$("#links").change(function() {

    //var matches = new array();
    var linksStr = $("#links").val();
    var pattern = new RegExp("^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$","g");
    var matches = linksStr.match(pattern);

    for(var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
      alert(matches[i]);
    }

})
```

It doesn't capture this url (I need it to):

> http://www.wupload.com/file/63075291/LlMlTL355-EN6-SU8S.rar

But it captures this

> http://www.wupload.com

Comment: it does capture that one :P `alert("http://www.wupload.com/file/63075291/LlMlTL355-EN6-SU8S.rar".match(/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/g))`

Comment: Now firebug says 'Regular expression too complex' :(

Comment: that's odd... idk. i'm using Chrome and it worked in Chrome's js console.

Comment: @Joseph try it with multiple urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things:

1. The main reason it didn't work, is when passing strings to `RegExp()`, you need to slashify the slashes.  So this:

   ```
   "^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$"
   ```

   Should be:

   ```
   "^(https?:\/\/)?([\\da-z\\.-]+)\\.([a-z\\.]{2,6})([\/\\w \\.-]*)*\/?$"
   ```
2. Next, you said that FF reported, "Regular expression too complex".  This suggests that `linksStr` is several lines of URL candidates.
   Therefore, you also need to pass the `m` flag to `RegExp()`.
3. The existing regex is blocking legitimate values, eg: "HTTP://STACKOVERFLOW.COM".  So, also use the `i` flag with `RegExp()`.
4. Whitespace always creeps in, especially in multiline values.  Use a leading `\s*` and `$.trim()` to deal with it.
5. Relative links, eg `/file/63075291/LlMlTL355-EN6-SU8S.rar` are not allowed?

Putting it all together (except for item 5), it becomes:

```
var linksStr    = "http://www.wupload.com/file/63075291/LlMlTL355-EN6-SU8S.rar  \n"
                + "  http://XXXupload.co.uk/fun.exe \n "
                + " WWW.Yupload.mil ";
var pattern     = new RegExp (
                    "^\\s*(https?:\/\/)?([\\da-z\\.-]+)\\.([a-z\\.]{2,6})([\/\\w \\.-]*)*\/?$"
                    , "img"
                );

var matches     = linksStr.match(pattern);
for (var J = 0, L = matches.length;  J < L;  J++) {
    console.log ( $.trim (matches[J]) );
}
```

Which yields:

```
http://www.wupload.com/file/63075291/LlMlTL355-EN6-SU8S.rar
http://XXXupload.co.uk/fun.exe
WWW.Yupload.mil
```

Comment: Thanks, I've used some of uber leet Jeff Atwood's regex - \bhttp://[^\s]+ for now

Answer (score 0):

Why not do make: 
  URLS = str.match(/https?:[^\s]+/ig);

Comment: If the URL is in a user-supplied text-box and is followed by a comma or full stop (as users often do!), those punctuation marks will be treated as part of the URL

Answer (score 0):

```
(https?\:\/\/)([a-z\/\.0-9A-Z_-\%\&\=]*)
```

this will locate any url in text